# Можно ли создать инициализированный двухмерный динамический массив?

Tags: c++

Можно ли в C++ создать инициализированный двухмерный динамический массив? Например, чтобы следующий массив стал динамическим:

```
int array[3][8] =
{
    {50, 200, 1000, 2500, 5000, 20000, 50000, 10000000},
    {50, 50, 100, 300, 500, 1500, 3000, 5000},
    {79, 89, 156, 252, 381, 494, 532, 965}
};
```

Я думал сделать что-то вроде

```
auto array = new int[3][8];
```

Но в этом случае каждому элементу значение нужно вручную присвоить.

```
array[4][3] = 4;
```

Comment: Он инициализируется так же, как и статический массив. Только отучайтесь писать = при инциализации.

Comment: Спасибо. Получилось. Знак "=" не нужно ставить.

Comment: инициализированный двухмерный динамический массив не имеет смысла для любого хорошего кода.

Comment: вопрос не в хорошем или плохом коде, а в возможности создания такого массива. Я изучаю C++ и хочу понять азы. Оператор goto не рекомендуют использовать, но это не значит. что про него не надо знать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Динамический массив инициализируется вот так:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    auto array = new int[3][8]
    {
        {50, 200, 1000, 2500, 5000, 20000, 50000, 10000000},
        {50, 50, 100, 300, 500, 1500, 3000, 5000},
        {79, 89, 156, 252, 381, 494, 532, 965}
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++ j)
        {
            cout << array[i][j] << " " << endl;
        }
        
        cout << endl;
    }


    delete[] array;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Еще раз - отучайтесь писать = при инциализации...

Comment: @user7860670 вам будет тяжело уламывать Си-шников писать такое : `for ( int i ( 0 ) ; ..` Все учебники упакованы совсем другим примером.

Comment: @AlexGlebe Тем, кто пишет `int i ( 0 )` тоже стоит отучаться от этого безобразия.